# Angular exhausMap issue?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have login method which need to make two calls before move it to next page. The first method invoke login api and return token. I'm saving this token to localStorage and fetch from header interceptor. Second call return username and display name and when finish a both calls I route user to logged page.

I think the best solution for two calls exhausMap but I did not use before and I don't know how to merge these two method in exausm map. If someone can write syntax for that.

THanks in advance.

This is mehthod:

```
login(type: string, email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
        this.url = '';
        const reqUrl = `${environment.api_url}${'users/logins'}`;
        this.url = `${reqUrl}`;

        return this.post(
            {
                type,
                profile: { email, password },
            }).pipe(
                catchError(this.errorHandlerService.handleError),
                tap(response => {
                    console.log('1', response);
                    this.storageService.saveToken(response.accessToken);
                }));

        this.userService.getUserInfo()
            .pipe(
                catchError(this.errorHandlerService.handleError),
                tap(response => {
                    this.handleAuthentication(
                        response.email,
                        response.displayName
                    );
                    console.log('2', response.displayName);
                })
            );
    }

    private handleAuthentication(email: string, displayName: string): void {
        const user = new User(email, displayName);
        this.user.next(user);
        this.storageService.saveUser(user);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The great thing about observables is that you can chain them together into one fluid action:

```
  login(type: string, email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    const reqUrl = `${environment.api_url}${'users/logins'}`;
    this.url = `${reqUrl}`;

    const profile = { email, password };
    return this.post({ type, profile }).pipe(
      exhaustMap(response => {
        console.log('1', response);
        this.storageService.saveToken(response.accessToken);

        return this.userService.getUserInfo().pipe(
          tap(response => {
            this.handleAuthentication(
              response.email,
              response.displayName
            );
            console.log('2', response.displayName);
          })
        )
      }),
      catchError(this.errorHandlerService.handleError),
    );

  }
```

Here we are calling post which presumably uses Angular's HttpClient's `post`, which returns an observable that completes with a response. Then we use `exhaustMap` to project the source observable of the http call to another call. We could use `switchMap` here as well, but exhaustMap ensures the first post completes.

Note that if `this.post` doesn't complete, exhaustMap will prevent this from ever emitting.

Comment: Thanks man @inorganik, it works perfect, do you prefer use exhausMap or make same another solution in these cases ?

Comment: Glad to hear! Use exhaustMap if you don't want any http requests to be cancelled because another one was started - like if the user is rapid-fire clicking a button. That's exhausTMap with a T :)